Configure nginx load balancer to ip_hash on header instead of ip address
I've set up a NGINX load balancer behind a reverse proxy.
As a result, all incoming requests have the same IP address (that of the reverse proxy).
All these requests contain an “X-Forwarded-For” header containing the IP address of the client who launched the request.
Is it possible to configure NGINX to perform the ip_hash not on the IP address of the incoming request, but on the contents of this “X-Forwarded-For” header?
If not possible with NGINX, is it possible with another load balancer (apache, etc.)?
Note: I have no control over the reverse proxy settings.

You should try the Real IP function.
It should take the IP address from the X-Forwarded-For value and make it available in the $remote_addr variable (replacing the IP address of the reverse proxy). Also, other directives that use the $remote_addr should use the revised value.
For example:
set_real_ip_from  x.x.x.x;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;

where x.x.x.x is the IP address of the reverse proxy received by Nginx.
